# Prove integration by parts formula for forms

Tags: vector-spaces

Let M be an oriented k-manifold in $R^3$, where k ∈ {1, 2, 3}. If ω is a smooth (k − 1)-form in $R^3$and f : $R^3$ → R a smooth function, prove the following integration by parts formula for forms:
$\int_{M}$f dω = $\int_{∂M}$fω − $\int_{M}$df ∧ ω.

Assume the boundary ∂M of M is smooth and M can be a curve, a surface or a bounded region in $R^3$.

Any idea on how to start this one? Thank you.

Comment: Do you know Stokes' theorem for forms?

Comment: Yes. I know $\int_{M}$ dω = $\int_{∂M}$ ω.

Comment: Now apply it to $f\omega$. Once you succeed, you can write your own answer to your question and accept it.